# I have several linux distributions installed, but can only make changes to GRUB from one of them. How can I fix this?

Tags: linux, boot, grub

I currently have the following operating systems installed on my laptop (in order of installation):

- Windows 10
- Kali 2.0
- Kubuntu 15.10

Everything works fine when I start the laptop. I get the GRUB menu and I can choose which OS to boot. They all boot fine and I have not encountered any problems pertaining to OS functionality.

However, when I try to make changes to GRUB from Kubuntu (such as using "update-grub" or "grub-customizer"), the changes do not register. I can only make changes to GRUB from Kali.

Why is this, and how can I change this so that I can edit GRUB from Kubuntu?

For the record, when GRUB starts it has a Kali background image, which makes me think that GRUB is somehow strictly connected to Kali.

Comment: stop using grub. its way more hassle than it is worth.

Comment: @mikeserv Do you recommend alternatives?

Comment: Do you have a separate /boot partition in common for both? Do you have an UEFI system (if yes you might try systemd-boot)?

Comment: @RobertL - yes. google mikeserv grub.

Comment: @cylgalad I do not have a separate /boot partition. Maybe it's only installed to the kali partition so only kali can make changes to it? I'll look into reinstalling and making a separate partition.